# How to skip function if div height greater than

Tags: jquery

I have some jQuery that is limiting the height of a certain div and adding a button below to expand/show the hidden portion.

I would like to only hide the div & show the button if the div height is greater than the minimum height I've set, `closeHeight`.

This is my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var closeHeight = '20'; /* Default "closed" height */
    var moreText    = 'Read More'; /* Default "Read More" text */
    var lessText    = 'Read Less'; /* Default "Read Less" text */
    var duration    = '1000'; /* Animation duration */
    var easing      = 'linear'; /* Animation easing option */

    // Limit height of bio wrapping div
    jQuery('.single-artist-content .artist-bio-wrap').each(function() {

        var current = jQuery(this).children('.read-more-wrap');

        if (current.height() > closeHeight) {

            // Set data attribute to record original height
            current.data('fullHeight', current.height()).css('height', closeHeight + 'em');

            // Insert "Read More" link
            current.after('<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="more-link closed">' + moreText + '</a>');

        } else {
            // Do nothing
        }

    });

// Link functinoality
    var openSlider = function() {
        link = jQuery(this);
        var openHeight = link.prev('.read-more-wrap').data('fullHeight') + 'px';
        link.prev('.read-more-wrap').animate({'height': openHeight}, {duration: duration }, easing);
        link.text(lessText).addClass('open').removeClass('closed');
        link.unbind('click', openSlider);
        link.bind('click', closeSlider);
    }

    var closeSlider = function() {
        link = jQuery(this);
        link.prev('.read-more-wrap').animate({'height': closeHeight + 'em'}, {duration: duration }, easing);
        link.text(moreText).addClass('closed').removeClass('open');
        link.unbind('click');
        link.bind('click', openSlider);
    }

    // Attach link click functionality
    jQuery('.more-link').bind('click', openSlider);

});
```

It was working before I put in the actual conditional `if (current.height() > closeHeight)` so I know that must be the problem, but I can't figure out why.

Can anyone help spot what I'm doing wrong with this? Thanks!

**EDIT:** Code above edited with the correct answer.

Comment: inside that function you want to skip, check width first, if greater than the minimum height I've set, just call `return` to end the function call

Comment: You are comparing apples to oranges. I.E. `if (500 > '20em') { ... }`.

Comment: I think this comes down to the fact that your closeHeight is a string. So you're comparing a string to a number. Edit: Daerik beat me to it

Comment: @Daerik I just noticed that as well. Edited my code above.

Comment: @dmoz Does it still break?

Comment: .children() is only ? it might return an array as well. since dom is not here

Comment: Looks like that did it. Had to make sure 'em' wasn't in the `closeHeight` variable, and added the 'em' string to both the conditionally skipped function and the `closeSlider` function as well. Corrected code above. Thanks everyone!

Comment: But, aren't you then comparing the value to 20 pixels, not 20 em?

Answer (score 1):

The function `height()` is returning a number in pixels with no unit.  But, you're comparing it to `20em` which will never match.  Also, you're comparing an integer (returned from `height()`) to a string (`20em`).

One way you could find out how tall 20em is in pixels would be to create a fake object, set it to to 20em, then grab the actual `height()` of that element.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var closeHeight = '20em'; /* Default "closed" height */
    var moreText    = 'Read More'; /* Default "Read More" text */
    var lessText    = 'Read Less'; /* Default "Read Less" text */
    var duration    = '1000'; /* Animation duration */
    var easing      = 'linear'; /* Animation easing option */


    //Here's where you can fix your closeHeight value:
    $fakeEl = jQuery("<div></div>").height(closeHeight); //set the element to closeHeight 20em
    closeHeight = $fakeEl.height(); //set closeHeight to an integer in pixels
    $fakeEl.remove(); //probably unnecessary because you  never appended it to the DOM.
    
    // Limit height of bio wrapping div
    jQuery('.single-artist-content .artist-bio-wrap').each(function() {

        var current = jQuery(this).children('.read-more-wrap');

        if (current.height() > closeHeight) {

            // Set data attribute to record original height
            current.data('fullHeight', current.height()).css('height', closeHeight);

            // Insert "Read More" link
            current.after('<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="more-link closed">' + moreText + '</a>');

        } else {
            // Do nothing
        }

    });

// Link functinoality
    var openSlider = function() {
        link = jQuery(this);
        var openHeight = link.prev('.read-more-wrap').data('fullHeight') + 'px';
        link.prev('.read-more-wrap').animate({'height': openHeight}, {duration: duration }, easing);
        link.text(lessText).addClass('open').removeClass('closed');
        link.unbind('click', openSlider);
        link.bind('click', closeSlider);
    }

    var closeSlider = function() {
        link = jQuery(this);
        link.prev('.read-more-wrap').animate({'height': closeHeight}, {duration: duration }, easing);
        link.text(moreText).addClass('closed').removeClass('open');
        link.unbind('click');
        link.bind('click', openSlider);
    }

    // Attach link click functionality
    jQuery('.more-link').bind('click', openSlider);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that .height() gets the computed height, not a string as '20em' is. So, your comparison might even fail and it might return to false.

the if condition will fail.

I would advise to use bootstrap or some other responsive framework instead, but if you still want to stick with this approach, compare similar properties, like setting height of a hidden div and then comparing heights of 2 divs intead.

Step 1. Create a hidden div, set its height to '20em'

Step2. Compare height of first div with the hidden div

Comment: This answer is very ambiguous. Please be more specific.